Pass Data from Ajax to method in ASP.NET 8 controller
This is my ajax script that use in jQuery step library. After get data from GET method in several step correctly and get with this Ajax method correctly:
  onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
      event.preventDefault();  
      console.log("Finish was clicked !");

      var postData = {

          CartAddresses: {
              address: $('#reviewAddress').val(),
              state: $('#reviewState').val(),
              district: $('#reviewDistrict').val(),
              zipCode: $('#reviewZipCode').val()
          },

          CartDeliveryDateViewModel: {
              deliveryDate: $('#deliveryDate').val(),
              deliveryTime: $('#deliveryTime').val(),
              details: $('#details').val(),
              PaymentMethod: $('#paymentMethod').val()
          },

          tax: parseFloat($('#tax').val()),
          totalPrice: parseFloat($('#totalPrice').text()),
          finalPrice: parseFloat($('#finalPrice').text())
      };
      //change to serialize with stringify
      var postDataJson = JSON.stringify(postData);

      console.log('postData', postData);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/UserPanel/CheckOut",  
          data: JSON.stringify(postData),
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (response) {
             
              if (response.success) {
                  alert("Checkout was successful!");
                
                  window.location.href = "/UserPanel/OrderConfirmation";
              } else {
                  alert("There was an error processing the checkout: " + response.message);
              }
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            
              alert("An error occurred: " + error);
          }
      });

  }

But in post controller it does not pass to method and all data input are null. All data get correctly and I checked n console but does not get to controller input, I use [FromForm] too, but does not pass data.
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("/UserPanel/Checkout")]
public IActionResult Checkout ( CheckOutViewModel checkOutViewModel)
{
    if (checkOutViewModel != null)
    {       
        bool isCheckoutSuccessful = true;

        if (isCheckoutSuccessful)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Checkout completed successfully." });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "There was an error completing the checkout." });
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        return BadRequest("Invalid data received.");
    }
}

This is my view model:
public class CartViewModel
{
    public List<CartItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<CartItemViewModel>();
    public List<CartAddressViewModel> CartAddresses { get; set; }
    public CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails CartDeliveryDateViewModel { get; set; }
    public int SelectedContactInfoId { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Items.Sum(item => item.ChefFoodsPrice * item.Quantity);
        }
    }

    public decimal FinalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return TotalPrice + (TotalPrice * Tax / 100);
        }
    }

    public enum CartViewModelResult
    {
        CartCreatedSuccess,
        CartCreatedFail,
        CartNotFound
    }
}

And get all of them in Checkout method (Get).
I get all of them from session or database. But in final step for finishing in Jquery step library I get all of them from script correctly. I create new viewmodel for checkout and want to after that add to data base:
public class CheckOutViewModel
{
    public CartAddressViewModel CartAddresses { get; set; }
    public CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails CartDeliveryDateViewModel { get; set; }

    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalPrice { get; set; }
}


Try adding the [FromBody] attribute: public IActionResult Checkout ([FromBody] CheckOutViewModel checkOutViewModel). Besides, you need to show us the implementation of the CheckOutViewModel  class.

@YongShun as I said FromBody doesnot work too. I change the script just with 1 data, does not work too,, any data doesnot gor to method

@Jackdaw I checked. data was receiving correctly as a joson, but they does not pass to method after break point

@maryamforex: By the way,  the $.ajax call uses postDataJson parameter name. To make the binding work properly use the same name in the action method, instead of checkOutViewModel.

@Jackdaw I need the data for adding these to data base after writing method. so how can I pass the data ? it is a jQuery step and with click on finish on form I had to transfer all data that get from ( get checkout method) and pass it to post. How can I do it now? I write the codes on asp.net core

@Jackdaw I updated the question and add my view models and Get method

When sending data to the server define the contentType  as  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'. Actually this is the default value which is fine for most cases.
Change the .ajax call like the following:
 $.ajax({
     url: '/UserPanel/Checkout',
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
     data: { checkOutViewModel: postData },
     success: function (response) {
         console.log('Checkout successful:', response);
     },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         console.error('Checkout failed:', status, error);
         alert('Error sending data. Please try again.');
     }
 });

The data parameter is referencing to the checkOutViewModel name using in the Checkout() action method of the UserPanel controller.
Finally, the jQuery generates the data string from the object postData you are providing. Therefore, no need to make JSON.stringify(postData); call.

this script does not work. but I found that , when I put one by one data , it works and pass to Checkout method post , ( for example tax, then finalPrice,,,,) it works but if I put all to gether method does not work and does not pass and became null, I set on program for camle case and change my properties to new edit question with lower case
